# Avoiding warning "Use of this in closure"

Tags: javascript, jquery

When i wrote this code i have 2 warnings "Use of this in closure"

```
 function tableIntoJson(){
    var tableArray = [];
    var columnIndex=0;
    var rowIndex=0;
    $('table#editable tr:not(#head)').each(function() {
        var tableData = $(this).find('td:not(#head)');
        tableArray[rowIndex]=[];
        if (tableData.length > 0) {
            columnIndex=0;
            tableData.each(function() {
                tableArray[rowIndex][columnIndex]=$(this).text();
                columnIndex++
            });
        }
        rowIndex++;
    });
    var jsonString=JSON.stringify(tableArray);
    return jsonString;
}
```

Warnings annoying me)).How can i replace "$(this)"?

Comment: What does emit that warning for you?

Comment: The warning is wrong as there is nothing wrong with your use of `this` in any way.

Comment: This warnings emit by Cloud9 ide

Comment: In events i can replace $(this) by $(event.target) but how can i do it here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though it's a valid use of `this`, if you want to keep your IDE happy, replace

```
$('table#editable tr:not(#head)').each(function() {
    var tableData = $(this).find('td:not(#head)');
```

with

```
$('table#editable tr:not(#head)').each(function(trIndex, tr) {
    var tableData = $(tr).find('td:not(#head)');
```

(and similar for the next `.each`).

It is also more readable than using `this`, since in this fashion you explicitly know what each loop iterates.